# how to only get the increment by 2 index of a list without error?

Tags: python

I have 3 list `All_string_position[0,5,6,8,9,11]` , `startPosition[]` and `endPosition[]`. The `startPosition[]` will get the every first index and the `endPosition[]` will get second index.

GOAL: `startPosition[0,6,9]` and `endPosition[5,8,11]`

What i tried:

```
All_string_position = [1,5,6,9] 
endPosition = []  
startPosition = []     
for i in range(len(All_string_position)):
        startPosition=All_string_position[i]         
        endPosition=All_string_position[i+1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slicing:

```py
All_string_position = [0,5,6,8,9,11]

startPosition = All_string_position[::2]
endPosition = All_string_position[1::2]

print(startPosition) # [0, 6, 9]
print(endPosition) # [5, 8, 11]
```

`lst[a:b:c]` picks elements from `lst`, starting from `a` (inclusive), ending at `b` (exclusive), and with increment of `c`. Each can be omitted.